# Select while inserting?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm not sure if it's possible but I'm trying to do an insert while selecting for a value to do a +1. The reason I'm doing this is because my column is auto increments, but the values are all over the places.

Here's what I have so far and it won't let me do the insert:

```
insert into channels set chanid=(select chanid from channels where parent=2
order by chanid desc limit 1)+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an alias in the sub-query. It did the trick for me.

```
insert into channels
set chanid=(
    select c.chanid
    from channels as c
    where c.parent=2
    order by c.chanid desc
    limit 1
)+1
```

Reference: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6980

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into channels(chanid)
select chanid+1 from channels where parent=2 
order by chanid desc limit 1
```

Comment: does not work am trying to do this directly into mysql not via a php page

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly your question try this!

```
insert into channels set chanid=(select chanid+1 from channels where parent=2 order by chanid desc limit 1)
```

Comment: I have tried this way previously and it still does not let me - it says that I can't specify target table "channels' from udpate in from caluse

Answer (score 0):

To reset `auto-increment` values you can try

```
SET @var_count = 0;

UPDATE channels 
SET chanid = (@var_count := @var_count + 1);
```

or

drop `auto-increment` column and recreate it with `PRIMARY KEY` on it.

Comment: I would still need to do an insert... how can i do an insert and also take the last chanid of the respective equal values?

Comment: you can use LAST_INSERT_ID() to fecth last inserted id from table.

Comment: please give me an example on how to do this - am not using php for this